Create Meta tag synonym from [front-page] to [homepage]
Both these Meta site tags seem to be referring to the same part of the site
front-page - 25 Questions

For questions where to topic concerns the site's home page at https://stackoverflow.com/, showing "Top Questions", a button for asking a Q, and other details.

homepage - 76 Questions

For questions about the workings of the homepage of Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/

Disclosure: I'm a dev here, so I'm aware I could just make the changes directly, but would rather post for community discussion, consensus, and buy-in, per the regular process anyway.

That disclosure is the highlight of this question.

I agree, definitely about the same concept, the word "home page" is literally written in the front-page tag wiki.
I've created the synonym and merged them together. I kept the tag wiki and excerpt from front page since it, while not as good as it could be, was at least more descriptive than the text in the wiki for homepage.
